# How to use if elseif inside table row without making a new row?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-4

I want to make a code that can use `if else if` inside table row.

But I can't make it ,once I use `else if` statement inside table row it make a new row by it self.

I expect that it make a new column in the same row

Here's a code

```
<tbody>
    <?php $i = 1;
    $varpetugas = null;
    $varrealisasi = null;
    ?>

    <?php foreach ($petugas as $k) : ?>
        <tr>
            <?php if ($k['nama_petugas'] != $varpetugas) : ?>
                <th scope="row"><?= $i++; ?></th>
                <td><?= $k['jenis_survey']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?= $k['nama_petugas']; ?>
                    <?php $varpetugas = $k['nama_petugas']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $k['target']; ?></td>
                <td><?= $k['realisasi']; ?></td>
                <?php $varrealisasi = $k['realisasi']; ?>
            <?php elseif ($k['nama_petugas'] == $varpetugas) : ?>
                <td>
                    <?= $k['target']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?= $k['realisasi']; ?>

                </td>
                <?php $varrealisasi = $k['realisasi']; ?>
                <?php $varpetugas = $k['nama_petugas']; ?>


            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

as you can see what I expected is `else if` statement show the output in a same row but , here's the result

[image]

Comment: pre normalize your data/array, so it only requires you to foreach over each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do new row (`<tr>`) every time when loop (next line after `foreach`).

But what you want to do is to have it only when condition (`<?php if ($k['nama_petugas'] != $varpetugas) : ?>`) is true.

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($petugas as $k) : ?> 
        <?php if ($k['nama_petugas'] != $varpetugas) : ?>
            <?php if ($i > 1) : ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <tr>            
            <th scope="row"><?= $i++; ?></th>
            <td><?= $k['jenis_survey']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?= $k['nama_petugas']; ?>
                <?php $varpetugas = $k['nama_petugas']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $k['target']; ?></td>
            <td><?= $k['realisasi']; ?></td>
            <?php $varrealisasi = $k['realisasi']; ?>
        <?php elseif ($k['nama_petugas'] == $varpetugas) : ?>
            <td>
                <?= $k['target']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $k['realisasi']; ?>

            </td>
            <?php $varrealisasi = $k['realisasi']; ?>
            <?php $varpetugas = $k['nama_petugas']; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if ($i > 1) : ?>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**PS:** Why do you have `elseif`? You can simply do just `else`. Isn't it?

Comment: it worked .about the elseif indeed i can use else , but i wanna make another else if with another condition for each coloumn. i stucked when i wanna make conditionn inside table row , so i made a example to make it . thanks, you are very helpful .